# How to set padding in header cells of htmlTable package?

Tags: r

I am using htmlTable package in my rmarkdown files. For setting cell padding I use this piece of code:

```
htmlTable(..., css.cell = "padding-left: .5em; padding-right: .2em;")
```

How can I do something similar on the header cells?

Comment: looks like you can't within the function. you can use a custom css to do so or set the style within the rmarkdown file such as `<style>th {padding-top: 2em;}</style>`

Comment: Thanks @rawr I will give that a try.

Comment: That doesn't work. Any ideas about where to put the code exactly in the document?

Comment: Now it worked. I put the the piece of style code in a .css file and referred to it in the YAML like: css:tables.css

Comment: you can put it anywhere

Answer (score 9):

The key is to add the `+ 1` rows when specifying the `css.cell` matrix argument. The default is to only affect the data-cells. Here's an example:

```
simple_output <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
htmlTable(simple_output,
          header = LETTERS[1:2],
          css.cell = rbind(rep("background: lightgrey; font-size: 2em; padding-left: .5em; padding-right: .2em;", 
                               times = ncol(simple_output)),
                           matrix("", 
                                  ncol = ncol(simple_output), 
                                  nrow = nrow(simple_output))))
```

Answer (score 0):

New to R I really appreciate this fantastic htmlTable package thank you Max Gordon.

The +1 did not work for me for some reasons (I have some tspanner?).

You can still do the formatting by adding the html code to your rownames, e.g. I want to format in italic the NA's rows header in my table:

```
rl[which(rl == "NA's")] <- rep("<i>NA's", length(which(rl == "NA's")))
```

Where rl is the vector of my rows headers

Hope it helps